# CODE doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, rest

Creating a random quote generator but the JS/jQuery code doesn't seem to work!!

***when i click the "new quote" button nothing happens, also the "tweet out" button doesn't work as it is supposed to!***

Here's the code pen link:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWObpZ

Code(if link not working...):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  getQuote();
  var randomQuote="";
  var author="";

  function getQuote(){

    var url = "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en";

    $.getJSON(url,function(data){

      randomQuote=data.quoteText;
      author=data.quoteAuthor;

      $(".quote").html('"'+randomQuote+'"');
      $(".author").html(" -"+author);
    });
  }

  $("#newQuote").on("click",function(){
    getQuote();
  });

  $("#tweet").on("click", function(){
    window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+randomQuote+" -"+author);
  });

});
```

Comment: _doesn't seem to work_ -- which part, exactly, doesn't work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question...

Comment: Please include the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem here. Links can (and do) die making the question useless.

Comment: Your title doesn't describe your problem adequately.

Answer (score -1):

It is CORS issue. You can use JSONP or enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin flag in header request to access jSON data.